# Generate unbalanced sample

Tags: probability, sampling, combinatorics, finite-mixture-model

Suppose we have $N$ individuals consisting of two different groups, A and B. Each group contains $N/2$ people. The label of each individual $Z$ follows a binary distribution with probability $P(Z=A)=P(Z=B)=1/2$ independently. We don't know which group each person belongs to.

Is there any strategy to generate samples from the total population such that, the samples contain imbalanced samples of groups A and B with a probability larger than $0$ when $N\rightarrow\infty$? For example, we need to generate $N_1+N_2$ samples from the population $N$, the samples should contain $N_1$ individuals from group A and $N_2$ people from group B with $N_1=CN_2$.

Suppose we can sample for any finite times, with a polynomial speed increasing with N.

Thanks to @J-J-J's comment, let's consider the following situation. People are voting for option A vs. option B, we want to study these voters on various other variables, and for some reasons we need to oversample people who voted A - but you also need to keep their individual votes completely secret (including to ourselves).

Comment: What relationship, if any, is there between "groups" and "labels"?  The two cannot be the same, because in the first case each group has $N/2$ people but in the second case the groups can contain any number of people between $0$ and $N.$

Comment: Certainly there is. Set $N$ and $p<0.5$. Generate $N$ A and B with equal probability. Out of the first $N$ samples, reject any beyond the first $pN$ As. For the rejected samples, generate new samples, and reject any additional As. (Of course, it will be simpler to just fill up with Bs.) It does not really make a lot of sense to discuss the distribution of labels after you are done selecting only the ones that you like, though... Can you explain the background of your question?

Comment: @whuber I mean the total population contains $N/2$ people from both groups A and B. I need to sample from the total population to generate an imbalanced subpopulation, which contains people from groups A and B with a certain proportion.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I mean we need to sample from a population without knowing exactly which persons to any group.

Comment: More context would be useful. For instance, is it a situation where people are voting for an option A vs. an option B, you want to study thse voters on various other variables, and for whatever reason you need to oversample people who voted A - but you also need to keep their individual votes completely secret (including to yourself)? There *might* be some solutions - but it completely depends on the details of your situation, this is why more information would be useful.

Comment: @J-J-J Yes, I think my case is exactly what you describe. Is there any solution?

Comment: @FangzhiLuo The possible solutions I might have are more related to logistic than to statistics. They require voluntary participation from the voters, and being at least partly in control of the vote organization. If you're *really* in this situation, a very simple solution is to replace the vote by an anonymous survey asking multiple questions to respondents ("Do you vote for A or B? what is your gender?" etc.). Once you collected enough data, randomly discard a certain % of answers from group B, so you'll have a sample where group A is oversampled. .../...

Comment: If you can't do that during the vote, another solution (requiring to contact *all* voters after the vote), is to assign a unique random identifier to each voter before the vote, that only them will know. Depending on the circumstances, you may have to keep an anonymous list of all these ids. At the time of the vote, ask voters what is their unique identifier, so you'll know which identifier is attached to each vote. After the vote, contact all voters to have them pass a new anonymous survey where you ask them their identifiers. You'll be able to discard responses in the same fashion as above.

Comment: For the second solution described above, you should organize things so it's absolutely impossible for anyone to make a connection between the identity of a person and her unique identifier. Also note that a survey could involuntary break the secrecy of votes, no matter what. For instance, if there's only one woman aged over 60 among the voters, and if you ask the gender and age of respondents during your survey, and then match these data against individual votes, absolutely no solution will protect her anonymity and the secrecy of her vote, unless you restrict enough the scope of the survey.

Comment: @J-J-J Thanks for your solution, it is helpful. However, in my case, I already got the data.  In the data, I don't have the identity of the individuals, and I don't know which group they belong to. Instead of thinking of additional surveys, I am wondering about methods to oversample one group only based on the data. I guess this can somehow be achieved by subsampling or bootstrap, but I am not very sure.